# How to use same labels in a deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm trying to pass same label to a deployment, Both deployments have different image and environment variables. I'm using the same label so i can group the metrics together.

But the deployment is failing. Can someone please point me a workaround or is it because of the api version i'm using?

Deployment1:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: stg-postgres-exporter-pgauth
  namespace: prometheus-exporters
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        db: foo
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/port: "9187"
        prometheus.io/job_name: "postgres-exporter"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: stg-rds-exporter
          image: wrouesnel/postgres_exporter:v0.8.0
          ....
```

Deployment2:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: stg-rds-exporter-pgauth
  namespace: prometheus-exporters
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        db: foo
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
        prometheus.io/port: "9042"
        prometheus.io/job_name: "rds-exporter"
        prometheus.io/path: "/basic"
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: stg-rds-exporter-pgauth
          image: hbermu/rds_exporter:latest 
          ....
```

Error:

15:27:39 The Deployment "stg-rds-exporter-pgauth" is invalid: spec.template.metadata.labels: Invalid value: map[string]string{"db":"foo"}: `selector` does not match template `labels`

kubectl version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.1", GitCommit:"d647ddbd755faf07169599a625faf302ffc34458", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-02T23:49:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14+", GitVersion:"v1.14.9-eks-502bfb", GitCommit:"502bfb383169b124d87848f89e17a04b9fc1f6f0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-02-07T01:31:02Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: is there any selector in any of the deployment yamls?

Comment: No there isn't any selector.

Comment: You must define a selector @user6826691, check out my answer below.

Comment: so none of the deployment work or only one did not work?

Comment: only one did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes uses the labels and selectors to control the replicas of your Deployments, check the example below available in [k8s doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

You have the selector matchLabels:

```
selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
```

And the template labels:

```
template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
```

They have to match, and that's why your deployment is failing.

Kubernetes uses the labels to control the replicas of your Deployment, so I'd recommend adding a second label to your Deployments. That would make the selector unique, but you would still be able to query the entity by one of its labels.

Answer (score 1):

`.spec.selector` is a required field that specifies a label selector for the Pods targeted by this Deployment.
`.spec.selector` must match `.spec.template.metadata.labels`, or it will be rejected by the API.
In API version `apps/v1`, `.spec.selector` and `.metadata.labels` do not default to `.spec.template.metadata.labels` if not set. So they must be set explicitly. Also note that `.spec.selector` is immutable after creation of the Deployment in `apps/v1`

You should not create other Pods whose labels match this selector, either directly, by creating another Deployment, or by creating another controller such as a ReplicaSet or a ReplicationController. If you do so, the first Deployment thinks that it created these other Pods. Kubernetes does not stop you from doing this

Comment: If template.metadata has multiple labels defined then should we define all labels in the selector? example:
spec: replicas: 1 template: metadata: labels: app: foo-bar elastic-instance:foo